# When angular does not load on initial page, how to select, click element with protractor's element explorer

Tags: angularjs, element, protractor

I can't seem to select element and click them with protractor's element explorer.

e.g.

```
it('should do ', function(){
    browser.get('localhost:3000/myapp');
    browser.getCurrentUrl().then(val){
        console.log(val);
    }
    var profileIcon = element(by.css('profile-icon'));
    profileIcon.click(); // scenario 1
    profileIcon.isPresent(); // scenario 2
})
```

it will always return somethign like

```
There was a webdriver error: UnknownError unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw
exception: TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null
  (Session info: chrome=32.0.1700.76)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.8.241075,platform=Windows NT 6.2 x86_64) (WARNING
: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: 'Kwik-Desktop', ip: '108.209.248.41', os.name: 'Windows 8', o
s.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
```

the real prblem here seems to be that angular was not loaded on inital start up, how can I start poking around the buttons and stuff to get to the page where angular come into play via require.js?

Comment: as far as i understand the error, profileIcon is null. i guess your profile-icon is not an element but a css class. so it should be by.css('.profile-icon');

Comment: so how does by.css and element(by.css differ, I just want to know if there was a different selector or pratical usage.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are running Chrome, try to close the DevTools if you have them open.

For some reason I have been seeing the same error when accessing elements that exist on the page only if the Developer Tools are open.

Comment: ok, found the issue, looks like angular wasn't loaded on this particular page, wow definitely would need that for protractor to work, btw, ur solution shouldn't be the issue for you. Since the chrome devtool auto close on protractor actions.

Comment: After a recent update my devtools would not auto-close.  I am running Chrome 32.0.1700.77

Comment: Noticing same issue here too. `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null`

Answer (score 1):

The element explorer is a tool that will help you to test protractor selectors while you are writing a test.

Julie gave a presentation a couple of days ago and she gives a quick demo. Check this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQipuiTcn3U#t=815

Answer (score 0):

try using protractor's API.

```
var ptor = protractor.instance();

it('should do ', function(){
    ptor.get('#/myapp');
    ptor.waitForAngular();

    var profileIcon = protractor.By.css('.profile-icon');

    ptor.findElement(profileIcon).click();

});
```

Comment: i dont think that's any different, plus I'm using browser b/c angular was not loaded on initial page.